# How to push changes in a database to the client using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on an app which, among other things, pushes data to the client when an updation occurs on the database. The trouble is that the websocket on node.js listens to the databse on a different port then the node. The guy before me wrote a piece of code and then dumped it on me. The node looks somewhat like this:

```
var handler=http.createServer(function(req, res){
session(req, res, function(req, res, body) {
    if (!req.session || !req.session.data || !req.session.data.uid || req.session.data.uid == '' || !req.session.data.role || req.session.data.role =='') {
        var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if(req.method == 'GET' && uri =="/attendance-node/getMonthFromReport") {
        var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        var url_parts = url.parse(req.url,true);
        processgetMonthFromReport(req, res, uri, url_parts.query);
        return;
    }
        res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});  
        res.write("401 Unauthorized");
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    if(req.method == 'POST') {
        var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        var qs = require('querystring');
        var POSTVAR = qs.parse(body, '&', '=', {"maxKeys" : 0});
        //var POSTVAR=JSON.parse(body);
        handleRequest(req, res, uri, POSTVAR);
    }

    if (req.method=='GET') {
        var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        var url_parts = url.parse(req.url,true);
        handleRequest(req, res, uri, url_parts.query);

    }
});
}).listen(3014,"127.0.0.1");

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8077,"127.0.0.1");
sys.puts("websocket Server running on port 8077");

io.configure(function () {
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'xhr-polling','jsonp-polling']);
io.set('log level', 0);
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
io.sockets.emit('init',"i am working via websocket");
});
```

As you can see the node is listening on 3014 and the socket on 8077. Now how am I suppossed to provide an handler for the message received on the socket and forward it to the node's client?

Note: I am fairly new to web development. So basically I was thrown in the water and now I am learning to swim.

P.S. Also, what would the client side of the socket look like?

P.P.S. The database sending update notification to the socket is already taken care of. It comes as a POST request.
Thanx in advance!!

Comment: Are database updates (notifications) coming in on the websocket via port 8077 or through the webserver on 3014? Also is there any reason you aren't serving socket.io via the webserver?

Comment: @travis yes, the request are coming on the port 8077 and the request from client are coming on 3014. I need to receive request on 8077 and then emit a message to the client on 3014.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have socket.io also on the client side (browser?) as well.

I'd say the best solution would be to have socket.io run on the same port as your web server. However, if it this not possible and you must keep the web socket that the database uses separate from the web server you could run two instances of socket.io.

One would be attached to the web server, and the other would be for the database.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , IO = require('socket.io')
  , web_io = IO.listen(app)
  , data_io = IO.listen(8080)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

web_io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('some_event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

data_io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('database_update', function (data) {
    // Will be sent to everyone socket listening on port 80 (browser sockets mostlikely)
    web_io.sockets.emit('database_update', data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.sockets.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```